# Jquery .change() does not work after submit of form

Tags: jquery, jsp

I am pretty new to jquery. I have jsp form fields which change based on a drop down list.
But the jquery `.change()` method does not work once the page is submitted. Please let me know if i can use any other methods in place of `.change()`?

Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#form\\:select").change(function()
    {
   var value=    $("#form\\:select").val();

 if(value=="")
 {
    $("#fields").css("display","none");
 }else
{
  $("div","div#fields").hide();
 $("#fields").css("display","block");
  $("div#"+value).show();
      }
   });
 });
```

I have div tags that display different fields onchange of the dropdown.Once i submit the form the .change does not work.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: maybe `.live('change', function(){});` will help.

Comment: if you post your code we'll be able  to help you out

Comment: @Sem: `live` [is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/) in favour of [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, in order for Javascript to work, there needs to be Javascript loaded already on the page. By submitting the page, you're refreshing all the content in it, including the Javascript that was loaded in it, meaning that everything that was in that page is lost after you refresh the page. In order to make this work, you would need to manually post a value to the page, once you submit it, you would need to read the value via PHP and depending on what you want to do fire the Javascript function by using PHP.
It's basically like having a Javascript variable set to 1 and then refreshing the page. It will be set to 0 again because It's not saved anywhere.